# How to change the alias value on Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, alias, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I want to know if we have a way to change the value of the alias index ? I will give you examples;

For example we have a index that holds the credit card numbers;

4444-444-777 .... and so on,

Then I have a alias to that index, lets say alias1,

What I want to do is, once I call alias1, the user will automatically see;

xxxx-xxx-777 instead of 4444-444-777.

Can you please give me some ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with aliases.  Aliases have [functionality to filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) the query, but this is just an inclusion / exclusion filter.  For example, `alias1` could be a filtered alias that only allows the search query to see `user1` documents.

Aliases do not have any capability to actually modify or manipulate data.

There are some options, but they all have trade-offs.

**Script Fields**

You can use [Script Fields](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) to provide a "virtual" field.  Essentially, you run a script which loads some field, then performs whatever manipulation you need (e.g. `4444-444-777` -> `xxxx-xxx-777`).  This is then returned to you as an extra field in the search results.  The caveat is that the original data is still visible in the original `_source`, so your app will need to make sure that isn't exposed.

**Transform**

If you don't ever want the original data to be returned, you can perform a [Transform](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) which will physically alter the `_source` document before it is indexed.  This means that the data you get back from the search results will be pre-manipulated...but you will never be able to access the original data (because it has been transformed).

**Your application code**

It may be best to just perform this filtering in your application code.  Simpler, easier to change, not doing anything fundamentally different from what ES would have to do anyway.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer actually I am trying to use script fields but there is something that i can not understand, can you please look at it ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105351/can-not-get-result-of-script-fields-in-elasticsearch