# Can not get result of "script_fields" in elasticsearch

Tags: java, groovy, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to use "script_fields" in order to set new values to my fields but I can not see the "field" that I have added on result set,{

```
  "query": {
    "my_type_x": xxx
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": "doc['my_type'].value * 3"
    }
  }
}
```

Once I launch this on elasticsearch I get no error and get the results without any problem but I can not see any "test1" with changed value.

Where do I need to review ? Can you please tell me if anything is wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was coming from the configuration of Elasticsearch. I just added,

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

and it started to work.